# Appropriate pattern for ActiveRecord class

Tags: php, oop, activerecord

I've got an ActiveRecord `BaseModel` class and a lot of classes-models which inherit from it. And i've got a class `Bookmark`, which is inherited from `BaseModel` as well.
Also, i've got `Decorator`-inherited classes, they implements special interface to represent single model ( `getModelView(model)` method). This is some pseudo-code:

```
TestModel inherits BaseModel
    getName:
        return this.name

BookmarkModel inherits BaseModel
    BaseModel model

    getBookmark:
        return this.model

TestDecorator inherits BaseDecorator implements SingleModelViewInterface:
    getView(model):
        return 'view' //html-view of model

BookmarkDecorator inherits BaseDecorator
    getBookmarksView(BookmarkModel[] bookmarks):
        foreach(bookmarks > bookmark):
            decorator = Relation::getDecoratorByModel(bookmark->getEntityType())
            decorator->getView(bookmark->getBookmark())
```

So, everything looks good, until i want to change that View for bookmarked model a bit. I want a to add a custom title for that view. And i can't make it inside decorator, because it renders it not only for a bookmarks.

EDIT: So, the problem is - seems that i need a decorator pattern, but i dont have anything to inherit from, because concrete TestDecorator using TestModel speical methods. So now i've done some really bad realization, using magic methods (PHP):

```
class BookmarkedModel {

    /** @var BaseEntityModel*/
    private $model;

    public function __construct(BaseEntityModel $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'Bookmark '.$this->model->getName();
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->model, $name), $arguments);
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->model->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        return $this->model->$name[$value];
    }

}
```

So it will work for now, but in terms of code structure, readability and stability it's really bad decision.

Comment: my 2cents : modify getBookmark() to return the model with the custom title. The View is just a renderer, it should remain generic.

Comment: getBookmark returns any model, which inherits from BaseModel. BaseModel has abstract method `getName()`. I've done some sort of a Decorator pattern (but it's not actual decorator, i don't have a class to inherit from.)

Comment: Now i'm thinking about adding `setName()` to `BaseModel`. And just setting it in `BookmarkModel` `getBookmark` method after getting it from database. I think it's easier decision. I don't think i'll face any other required functionality.

Comment: You **should never** name your classes as `Model`, including `BaseModel`. Model is an abstraction, its a layer that contain bunch of classes, by definition.

Comment: No i can't use LSP, because `getName` is overridden in all classes.

Comment: Aaahk. My eyes! They Bleeed! But more seriously, why is there a need to implement this all over again? Just use [phpactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) or use a proven object-relational mapper (ORM) like as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/). If this is legacy code and you *really* must, don't make matters worse by over-complicating things for yourself...

Comment: Potherca, question have nothing to do with ActiveRecord implementation. It's all around structure of decorators. Idk why someone edited my previous title.

Answer (score 2):

The model should be unaware of the view. Models represent the raw data seen from every angle at once. The view is a *perspective* of that model. The controller should feed the model *to* the view:

```
$model_view->render($model);
```

Then decorate the view:

```
$bookmark_view->render($model); // bookmark_view wraps a model_view,
// returns 'Bookmark '.$this->model_view->render($model)
```

Only decorate based on interfaces, not types.

PHP's magic methods are great, but they should not be used for ActiveRecord, this goes against "separation of concerns", in this case separating the model from it's persistence mechanism.

Instead make an ActiveRecord object and feed the model *to* it.

```
$record->store($model);
```

Then if you need to modify storage, again just decorate the storage mechanism:

```
$log_record->store($model); // wraps $record, logs a message prior to database storage.
```

Comment: How exactly this case helps with separating model from persistence mechanism? Basically, i don't see any advantages.

Comment: The first point is an example of proper decoration, that is, decoration only of interfaces, and separating the model from the view. The second point is to illustrate that making the object itself the storage mechanism introduces a complexity that scales with your object complexity, and is not easily swapped out or _unit testable_, as demonstrated by your attempt at wrapping your object. You would do better to make BookmarkedModel an extension of BaseEntityModel.

Comment: Models should only care whether they're in a valid state. That is their purpose. Not to persist themselves.